# Build a line graph in excel sheet

Tags: excel, graph, charts, linegraph

I have a table with the following data(PFA the image), requirement is to build a line graph with Date in X-Axis and Count in Y-Axis, the Systems should be of each series. When I select the Date column to get the Y-Axis the output is not as expected(PFA the image)

How do I form a line Graph with this data?

[image: The below image consists of the table]

Comment: "...the output is not as expected..." it would be helpful to know what the expected output is.

Comment: PFA the image, the output represents only system 3. Once I select the complete date the other series is not being represented. The desired output is all the 3 systems  to be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on any cell within the table and then select Pivot Chart and Pivot Table you can create what you want. See image. Hope this helps.[image: Build a line graph in excel sheet using Pivot tables]